# Cut Tool or Process to mimic cutting in a "cookie cutter" like fashion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, tools

Say I have a sidewalk polygon, and on that segment of sidewalk I have 5 tree grates that I want to cut out of the sidewalk polygon. Is there a tool or an easy process that I could cut out one tree grate in the sidewalk polygon once and be able to cut out 4 more with same exact dimensions as the first cut? As if I was using a cookie cutter to cut out consistent shapes? Besides just doing it manually, which leads to inconsistent shapes and takes a bit of time, I haven't been able to find anything that will recreate another cut that was done to a polygon.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Create shape on side of walk. Copy paste move clip in editing session

Answer (score 1):

Tree grates are circular or semicircular metal things that replace sidewalk right?  If you have the locations as points you could 1) buffer the points using the radius of the grate 2) and then use the Erase tool (Advanced ARcGIS license) to remove the grates from the sidewalks.

If you don't have an advanced license you can use the Union tool with the option NO_GAPS specified and then go in and manually delete the grates.  Or use Select by Location to select the points that represent grates and delete all features that overlap with them at once.